# How can I set Geany as the default text editor on Windows?

Tags: windows, geany

I'm trying to set Geany as the default program for opening .html files on Windows. Is it possible to do this?

I've noticed that Geany doesn't show up under the list of applications that appear when choosing the default program for opening a file.

Answer (score 1):

Hold your <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and right click on the file. You should have 'Open with...', and then probably you'll have some option to use the recommended application only (untick it).

If you still can't see your software in the list, type in your file selection popup (depending on your system, you should click on 'Browse...' to see the Select Folder Window):

```
*.*
```

And press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It'll enable all the extensions to look for.

Comment: What is the "window box", and how can I find it?

Comment: Depending on your system, once you selected 'Open with...' option, you should see something like: http://i.techrepublic.com.com/gallery/6338897-579-478.jpg To type '*.*', try click to 'Browse...'

Comment: You don't need to hold `Shift` when right clicking

Comment: By "your window box" you really mean "opened context menu"

Comment: @shuji I mean in the file selection popup.